# Why is context passed to the constructor of Intent?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand why we pass a `Context` instance to the `Intent` constructor? Why isn't it enough to do `new Intent(SomeActivity.class)`? Does Android enforce some restrictions or what?

I was trying to look at the code but all I find is that it gets the package name.

[Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify an Activity in an Android application unambiguously, you need to have both, the name of the application (aka Android application package), and the full name of the activity (java package name + class name of activity class). These are exactly those two parameters you give in constructor. Context is used to get Android application package name, and the class to get full class name.

An Activity with the same full name can be used in two applications. If you do not provide Context, then Android won't know which application an activity belongs to.

Comment: In this context I wanna ask, what if the other Activity to start is in different package for the same project. How would it succeed then?

Comment: @pulp_fiction Then you have same application package + full activity name (activity package name + activity class name).

Comment: Okay just confirming one thing then. Let's say you have an activity **Activity1** in *com.example.sample1* and you intend to start the Activity named **Activity2** in *com.example.sample2*. Considering the procedure that's being actually followed, here is what happens as I have come to understand: The *ActivityManager* gets the name of the package the calling activity is present in, then parses that string to retrieve the portion *com.example.* and then append it to the called Activity's name.

Comment: Or rather if the Activity is in different package, we have to specify it explicitly in the manifest file and that's where the ActivityManager uses to find the Activity. Which is it?

Comment: @pulp_fiction application package and java package of activity are two different things. Intent has both: application package (defined in android  manifest file) and java package of activity. ActivityManager takes application package first, finds the app where activity is located and then searches for activity by full name (java package + class name).

Comment: I just read another answer relating specifically to the Application package name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754538/android-app-package-name         Now everything adds up well. Thank You for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, the `Context` in the constructor is used to get the package name of the  application.

Inferring the package name from the class as in `SomeActivity.class.getPackage().getName()` does not work in every case, as it could be different from the application's package name.